# How to correctly submit POST positioning request via HERE API from a local environment?

Tags: json, geolocation, maps, here-api, geopositioning

I develop locally on Windows 10 using XAMPP stack.

http://localhost:8003/myFolder/

This is my code:

[Code snippet: URL without CORS mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dKKa.png)

**I get the following error:**
POST https://pos.ls.hereapi.com/positioning/v1/locate?apiKey=Lxj-xbibfpSHLMw1U...blabla
**net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)**

[Code snippet: URL with CORS mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP8Cp.png)

**I get the following error:**
POST http://host/path?CORSH=%7B%22Content-Type%22%3A%22application%2Fvnd.here.layerObjectList%2Bjson%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8%22%2C%22Accept%22%3A%22application%2Fjson%3B%20charset%3DUTF-8%22%2C%22GroupId%22%3A%22FGx1AWaAzKOo0imNkLmf%22%2C%22AuthServiceId%22%3A%22here_app%22%2C%22Auth-Identifier%22%3A%22Ykv6MmZ03OJtiFD4R7Ht%22%2C%22Auth-Secret%22%3A%22AXqUNisVW46XJs9_pxuzOzneKlYPrY5X_blablabla
**net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:

url = 'https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=Eichholz 27 ,+ 20459 ,+ Hamburg ,+ D&apiKey=yYoMr6vEReqc_sI0HAPMqIu3fYJdGcRsBR5t-xxxxxx' ;

$.ajax({
crossDomain: true,
type : 'get',
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
url : url ,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType : 'json',
jsonCallback : 'getJson',
async : false,
success : function(data) {
$.each(data, function(counter, daten) {

```
            alert('return -- ' + daten.titel) ;
        });
    },
    error : function(data, req, status, err) {
        alert('something went wrong !!! getLatLng(url)');
        // console.log('something went wrong', status, err);

    }
}); // ajax end
```

**Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=Winterfeldtstrasse%2079,+%2010781%20,+%20Berlin%20,+%20GERMANY&apiKey=yYoMr6vEReqc_sI0HAPMqIu3fYJdGcRsBR5t-xxxxx. (Grund: CORS-Anschlag schlug fehl)**

Answer (score 0):

in principal, AJAX did not support external URL.
If you must call aURL Like

url = 'https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=Eichholz 27 ,+ 20459 ,+ Hamburg ,+ D&apiKey=yYoMr6vEReqc_sI0HAPMqIu3fYJdGcRsBR5t-xxxxxx' ;

You must do it with $.getJSON .
Like:

```
   function getLatLng(url, location_id) {

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(counter, daten) {
        // alert(url);
        JSON.stringify(daten);
        // alert('return -- ' + counter + '-- ' + daten.title ) ;

        function print_r(printthis, returnoutput) {
            var output = '';

            if ($.isArray(printthis) || typeof (printthis) == 'object') {
                for ( var i in printthis) {
                    output += i + ' : ' + print_r(printthis[i], true)
                            + '\n';
                    // alert('for - ' + printthis[i]);
                }
            } else {
                output += printthis;
                // alert('else - ' + printthis + '--' + printthis[i]);
            }

            if (returnoutput && returnoutput == true) {
                return output;
            } else {
                // alert(output);
                var nlat = output.indexOf("lat : ", 10);
                // alert(nlat);
                var lat = output.substring((nlat + 6), ((nlat + 6) + 9));

                var nlng = output.indexOf("lng : ", 10);
                var lng = output.substring((nlng + 6), ((nlng + 6) + 9));
    alert('location_id - ' + location_id + '  lat ' + lat + '  lng ' + lng);
                updateAdress(lat, lng, location_id , todo)
            }

        }

        print_r(daten);
        // console.dir(daten);
    });     }); }
```